# AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'teardown_appcontext' in Google Deploy using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask

The problem is that everytime I deploy my app in google cloud it throws me an error to prevent the deploying. I'm trying to figure out the error and says `AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'teardown_appcontext'`. i'm trying to find a solution with this problem that maybe someone encounter this also, yet maybe mine is unique that no one encountered this. But it works on localhost.

and this is the error:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
[2019-11-14 16:14:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.0
[2019-11-14 16:14:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2019-11-14 16:14:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-11-14 16:14:41 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2019-11-14 16:14:42 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 133, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 331, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 89, in <module>
    from blueprints import *
  File "/home/vmagent/app/blueprints/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from blueprints.routes.defaults.index  import default_route
  File "/home/vmagent/app/blueprints/routes/defaults/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    minify(default_route)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_minify/main.py", line 64, in __init__
    app and self.init_app(app)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_minify/main.py", line 87, in init_app
    app.teardown_appcontext(self.teardown)
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'teardown_appcontext'
[2019-11-14 16:14:42 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2019-11-14 16:14:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-11-14 16:14:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Here is the main.py file:

```
#!/home/kimdev/Documents/pythonwebapp/flask_v1/bin/python3

import os
import yaml
import datetime

from flask         import Flask, session, make_response, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from functools     import wraps

def _directory():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def _file(fileTarget):
    return os.path.join(_directory(), fileTarget)

def isFileExists(fileTarget):
    return os.path.exists(_file(fileTarget))

def cookieCheckActive(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        _active = request.cookies.get('_active', '')
        _u      = request.cookies.get('_u', '')

        if _active != '' and _active == '1' and 'login' not in session:
            session['login']  = '1'
            session['userID'] = _u

            return redirect(url_for('business_dashboard.dashboard'))
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def ifLogin(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'login' in session and session['login'] == '1':
            return redirect(url_for('business_dashboard.dashboard'))
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def ifNotLogin(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cookieUserID = request.cookies.get('_u', '') if '_u' in request.cookies else None

        if 'login' not in session:
            return redirect(url_for('business_login.login'))
        # elif cookieUserID == None:
        #     '''
        #         I'm so confuse with this block of code; cause if i will not
        #         remember my session eventhough it must equals to NONE it return
        #         to true and store the cookie but when i reverse it, then the trouble
        #         comes in when you are logging in.
        #     '''
        #     if cookieUserID != session['userID']:
        #         session.clear()
        #
        #         today   = datetime.datetime.now()
        #         expires = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        #         expires = today - expires
        #
        #         response = make_response(redirect(url_for('business_login.login')))
        #
        #         response.set_cookie('_u', '', expires = expires)
        #         response.set_cookie('_active', '', expires = expires)
        #
        #         return response
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'\x0c\xcd\xc4\x95ri\xb9\xb2O\xea\xd9\xea\x87&*\xb3'

_dbconfig = yaml.load(open(_file('config/dbconnection.yaml')), Loader = yaml.FullLoader)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST']        = _dbconfig['DB_HOST']
app.config['MYSQL_USER']        = _dbconfig['DB_USERNAME']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']    = _dbconfig['DB_PASSWORD']
app.config['MYSQL_DB']          = _dbconfig['DB_NAME']
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

_mysql = MySQL(app)

from blueprints import *

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'page not found', 404

@app.context_processor
def inject_dateYear():
    return {'dateYear': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y')}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

here is my requirements.txt to upload all required library for my app:

```
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
flask_mysqldb
passlib
flask_wtf
PyYAML
wtforms
Flask-Minify
```

this is the app.yaml use to deploy my app:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

entrypoint: gunicorn -b:$PORT main:app
```

Comment: It seems the error is in the code, could you add your `main.py` file?

Comment: @llompalles but in local its working fine. but when i deploy it in google this error message occur. and already included the main.py file.

Comment: What's inside your `blueprints` module? Please include that here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to reproduce the same error as yours, given that I can't see what is inside your `blueprint` module. But note that the [Python3 runtime for App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) is different from your local environment in several aspects, including the [pre-installed system packages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#using_c_libraries_with_python).

My suggestion is that you run this app in a Docker container emulating your local environment setup and when it works deploy the Docker image to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/). To do so, you can inspire in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy).

Comment: I actually figure it out that the flask_minify is no longer working on the python3.8 version on the App Engine. but you have the good point, so i check this answer.